# Reading text file then converting UPPERCASE words to Uppercase "capitalize" the first character only and writing to text file

Tags: java, string, capitalization

I am trying to clean up a TextFile in which I need to convert
uppercase characters of the textFile to capitalized the first
character of them only and then write in in new file.

for example:

- intext = In general, my primary concern regarding this patient was    regarding her *CHEST PAIN*.
- outtext = In general, my primary concern regarding this patient was    regarding her *Chest Pain*.

I could find only `.toLowerCase` which convert all characters into
lower case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no inbuilt function to do what you're trying to do so you have to write your own or use a third party library. As a hint, you could go through the words and if the word is capitalized, you can use your own function to go through and ensure only the first letter is left capitalized. Try it first and post your code. (You can use `isUpper()`)

Comment: and as extension to @Dana use `substrings` to fetch only the content after the first letter

Answer (score 0):

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully(str)
```

using  [apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) you can capitalize first char

**Java doc comment**

```
public static String capitalizeFully(String str)
```

> Converts all the whitespace separated words in a String into
>   capitalized words, that is each word is made up of a titlecase
>   character and then a series of lowercase characters.
>
> Whitespace is defined by Character.isWhitespace(char). A null input
>   String returns null. Capitalization uses the Unicode title case,
>   normally equivalent to upper case.

```
 WordUtils.capitalizeFully(null)        = null

 WordUtils.capitalizeFully("")          = ""

 WordUtils.capitalizeFully("i am FINE") = "I Am Fine"
```